# jQuery convert latin number via persian number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change latin number to persian number, but my code work correct but this code convert all number even numbers inside the tags `<script>` and `<style>` !
I want replacing number in body no in  tags `<script>` and `<style>`

How can be prevented from convert numbers inside tags `<script>` and `<style>`?

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/187L0jvz/

```js
    persian={0:'۰',1:'۱',2:'۲',3:'۳',4:'۴',5:'۵',6:'۶',7:'۷',8:'۸',9:'۹'};
 function traverse(el){
  if(el.nodeType==3){
   var list=el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
   if(list!=null && list.length!=0){
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
     el.data=el.data.replace(list[i],persian[list[i]]);
   }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<el.childNodes.length;i++){
   traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
  }
 }
    traverse(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
<div style="display:none"><h3><a href="http://www.ar.com">&#1662;&#1588;&#1578;&#1740;&#1576;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740;</a></h3></div>
</script>
<style>#baste{background:#76BE0E;right:50px;width:220px;}</style>
<div id="baste" style="color:#76BE0E">
  5858585258
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use any tag inside `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are parsing and replacing symbols in the whole body of the document, including scripts and other tags. Try to parse only the container of those numbers:

```
var elementToBeParsed = document.getElementById('baste'); //find div with numbers
traverse(elementToBeParsed);
```

UPD:
If you need to parse the whole text of the page, I would wrap content with some div, so all other tags were outside of that container. Then call traverse with that div.

```
...    
<body>
  <style>.wrapper{background-color:#fff; .... }</style>
  <div id="content" class="wrapper">
     all the content here 123456
  </div>
  <script ...>...</script>
  <script ...>...</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I want replacing number in body no in  tags `<script>` and `<style>`

Comment: @Mehdi look at my updated answer. You need to call traverse with the #content element. So evertything INSIDE it will be parsed. scripts and style tags are outside. so they should be untouched.

Comment: No,It does not help me